# My OCX file is not regisrter on other system except mine

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, ocx

I made OCX file (MFC active x c++) with this guide: [LINK](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32789.step-by-step-tutorial-to-create-mfc-activex-control-which-can-be-used-in-html-pages.aspx)
This simple OCX just add tow numbers and show the result. I build it in release mood and for all platforms(x86 and x64). when I wrote: `regsvr32 D:\MathOCX.ocx` , It is registering successfully on my PC . That guide website has a simple html file to work with `MathOCX` , but that does not worked for me. When I copy my OCX to another system it shows this error :
[image]

when I searched in google, some one said should use c:\windows\sysWow64\regsvr32 to register the OCX, but that error occurred again, some one said should install `dependencywalker.exe` to check which dll is not near the file. I download and put that dll near my OCX file. But it does not changed and the error shows again.
What can I do now?

I used visual studio 2013. I have 64b os.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx

Comment: I am beginner in MFC c++ activex and I do not understand from your link. please help me.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with MFC or ActiveX, deploying the correct files is a general requirement for C++ programs.  You did not mention your VS version so nobody can give you a "click here to solve your problem" answer.  Just move on to the next project, you can get back to this one once you learn more.